# Form Tag issue in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a situation where I need to use form_tag in my view, which should go to update action of my controller(here Admin::ReleaseFeaturesController). How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just simple as like this

```
#in your view

<%= form_tag('/update') do -%> # => <form action="/update" method="post">

#your code goes here

<% end -%>
```

You should be having an **`update`** action defined in your **`ReleaseFeaturesController`** like this

```
def update

#your logic

end
```

For more Info,See this **[API](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/form_tag)**

Comment: if my controller is in admin namespace then <%= form_tag('/admin/release_feature/update') do -%>. Is this the way I should give?
if so then its raising
The action 'release_feature' could not be found for AdminController.